# Formato de arquivo FileUpload salvo no banco sql server 2008 com tipo Image

Tags: java, android, sql-server, asp.net, utf-8

Estou com um problema de encontrar a codificação certa para um arquivo que é salvo no banco por meio do FileUpload do asp.net em banco sql server 2008 com tipo Image. Preciso fazer a migração de um sistema web para um aplicativo Android usando um webservice em asp.net para comunicação com esse banco sql server, mas o formato salvo não está correspondendo com os arquivos já salvos. Não estou entendendo se é questão de codificação (ASCII, UTF-8, ...) ou problema com encode e decode de base64, ou se seria mais adequado tratar o arquivo como hexadecimal.

O arquivo é lido pelo sistema através do componente fileupload:
`arquivo.ARQUIVO = FileUpload1.FileBytes`
e depois tem o salvamento:
`contexto.SaveChanges()`

o tipo esperado pelo banco é o `Image` e o sistema web lê o arquivo normalmente depois de salvo.

Preciso fazer o mesmo processo através de um aplicativo Android nativo (java), então leio o arquivo, converto em base64 para enviar para o webservice que faz o decode do arquivo e salva no mesmo tipo no banco. Quando comparo a string do arquivo a cadeia de caracteres é diferente, portanto o sistema web entende como arquivo corrompido, apesar o aplicativo ler normalmente.

Já testei `command.Parameters.Add("@ARQUIVO", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytes;` para salvar, mas parece-me que antes desse salvamento o formato do arquivo já não é o mesmo do sistema web.

Comment: Não é base64 é array de bytes!

Comment: Não é uma boa pratica salvar arquivos no banco

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas é assim que preciso fazer.